# Securely distribute Android app directly

Tags: android, security, app-store

I am developing a paid app that I will be placing in the google play store, but I want to give away some copies of the app for free to reviewers, for promotions, etc. I know that I can just link to the apk file but that is not secure as anyone could then copy and re distribute it. My question is, is there a way to distribute an application outside of the google play store but in a secure manner? Are there other services that allow you to upload your apk and distribute the app to specific individuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about people redistributing your APK, anyone who can install your app can [retrieve the APK](http://notepad2.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/android-save-your-apk-files-from-google.html) from their phone and then make that APK available to others, if they wish.

A dedicated android app distribution service might have useful Play-Store-like features, but if that's not essential for you then you just need a non-public file distribution method.

Some possible means of distributing a file to a named set of individuals:

- Email it directly (depending on the size of your apk)
- Send it using a web-based file hosting + distribution tool (e.g. [sharefile.com](http://www.sharefile.com))
- Host it on a website with logins that you control.

Comment: Great...So in essence there is no such thing as secure distribution. Would QR codes be a better solution since the apk file cannot be placed on the computer and is instead installed directly on the device?

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting with QR codes; my understanding of distributing an app using a QR code is that the code will just have a URL or app store address in it (so you have the same problem). Google offer a [licensing service](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html#licensing) that can help.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm currently facing a similar task, I looked into [Zubhium](https://www.zubhium.com/docs/introduction/) and [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/). However, I haven't evaluated their potential, yet, I just browsed through the website. Maybe you can start from there.

Comment: I have looked at Zubhium, but it only allows for 25 users with their free plan. I was hoping there would be something that would allow 100+ users.

Comment: Okay, if I find something else in the next days during my own research I will let you know here

Comment: @rioneye Zubhium is now Vessel and no longer have restriction of 25 users. Give a try.